# awk ignore case

Tags: linux, bash, awk

```
file.txt

file format  = cust:hdb

file data =   ted Ref:4rm
```

> read -p "Cust:" cust

User key in: ted ref

```
grep -i -q "$cust" "file"
```

System able to ignore case and read the input

```
read -p "NewCust:" cust2
```

User key in: Ted Ref

> awk -F : -v OFS=: -v cust="$cust" -v cust="$cust2" -v hdb="$hdb"
>   '$1==cust && $2==hdb {$1=cust2;}1' file

How do i set this so that the awk can ignore the case and update to file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `IGNORECASE`, you can convert the item you are matching to lowercase in `GNU awk` with `tolower()`.

```
awk -F : -v OFS=: -v cust="$cust" -v cust="$cust2" -v hdb="$hdb" 'tolower($1)==cust && tolower($2)==hdb {$1=cust2;}1'
```

The GNU awk documentation offers [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Case_002dsensitivity.html#Case_002dsensitivity) on case sensitivity.

Comment: +1 for the right solution and it'll work in any modern awk, not just gawk.

Comment: do you mean `tolower($1)==tolower(cust)` ?

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, it probably should be since that comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
IGNORECASE=1 awk -F : -v OFS=: -v cust="$cust" -v cust="$cust2" -v hdb="$hdb" '$1==cust && $2==hdb {$1=cust2;}1' file
```

Comment: @user1745860 I believe I fixed his example. I didn't want to duplicate the answer since he was correct about setting `IGNORECASE=1` in the environment.

Comment: @jordanm : Setting the IGNORECASE: I believe it should not matter whether it is at the beginning or at the end as it was earlier, isn't it?

Comment: @Guru `awk 'BEGIN { print ENVIRON["IGNORECASE"] }'` indicates that it does matter. It may depend on shell.